# как в Tkinter перевести Entry в int?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Всем привет! есть строки запроса:

```
enterme = Entry (root, width = 10)
enterme2 = Entry (root, width = 10)
```

и есть в функции использование этой переменной:

```
ramdme = random.randrange (int(enterme),int(enterme2))
```

Возникает ошибка:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Entry'
```

Как мне полученное через Entry значение перевести в int?
Весь код:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import random
root=tk.Tk()
enterme = Entry (root, width = 10)
enterme_2 = enterme.get()
enterme2 = Entry (root, width = 10)
enterme2_2 = enterme2.get()
ramdme = random.randrange (int(enterme),int(enterme2))
enterme.place()
enterme2.place()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Естественно, что вы получаете ошибку, немного странно пытаться конвертировать поле ввода в число. Стоит сначала получить значение этого поля:

```
val = enterme.get()
int(val)
```

Comment: сейчас попробую...

Comment: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: Опять естественно, пустую строку невозможно преобразовать в число.

Comment: enterme = Entry (root, width = 10) -запрашиваю число, val = enterme.get(), получаю число из enterme, строка ведь не пустая? или чего то не хватает? если получить рандом из val и val2 то будет эта ошибка

Comment: @dimahimma, если что-то введете в поле ввода, то то и получите через `enterme.get()`. Если ничего не введете, то получите пустую строку. Про рандом вообще не понятно к чему это.

Comment: @insolor в том то и дело, я ввожу уже в окне tkinter в строку enterme число. потом по наводке sergey-gornostaev получаю это число через enterme.get(). а в рандоме просто использую введенное число. И хотя я в поле ввода tkinter ввел число- по ошибке как будто там ничего не введено

Comment: Покажите весь код. На 99% уверен, что у вас код получения данных из поля не в обработчике события, а просто дальше по коду расположен.

Comment: @sergey-gornostaev обновил вопрос

Comment: Строка `enterme_2 = enterme.get()` выполняется примерно на 15 миллисекунде после запуска, в этот момент поле ещё пустое. А когда вы вводите число, скрипт находится на строке `root.mainloop()`.

Comment: На 99% уверен, что у вас код получения данных из поля не в обработчике события, а просто дальше по коду расположен- вот это было решение, спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @sergey-gornostaev чтобы не создавать новый вопрос, еще вот что интересно: при помощи этого root.update() обновляю окно программы. но если долго выполняется действие, то программа подвисает на секунду. можно сделать root.update() чаще выполнения функции? или на постоянку, чтоб например каждые пол секунды апдейт был?

Comment: @dimahimma, если выполняется какое-то долгое действие, которое нельзя разбить на более мелкие - тогда нужно выносить в отдельный поток/процесс, а это уже отдельная большая тема.

Answer (score 0):

Вы переводите в число **сам виджет Entry**. А хотите преобразовать в int **данные** из поля ввода. Поэтому предварительно их нужно получить:

```
int(entrme.get())
```